# Usage of indoor HDRI for correct dimensions

Tags: hdri, dimensions, photorealism

Right now, I'm using Blender to render objects I drew (even with other softwares) in order to produce images (or videos) that help to understand the real size of the object in a known context. For example, say I have to draw a soap holder, I want to show it inside a bathroom to easily understand its real size.

As far as I understand, to avoid to model and render every single item in a place HDRIs come to help.

I'm aware they are not a "real" 3D model, in fact I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsAUfQlZH_w) tutorial to create the dome (semi-sphere) where my objects can live.

Still I have hard-time to make the scene realistic. The first question is: how much big should be the dome?

Let's try with an example. I have this table that have a diameter of about 650 mm:

[image]

(by the way, how to show dimensions for imported objects?)

Now, without the dome, enabling an HDRI leads to the known "floating" issue:

[image]

But using the dome, it looks weird enough:

[image]

My goal is to add this table, and other objects, inside the room with the proper dimensions so they look realistic.

Can you give me a basic example please? Or a specific tutorial where I can learn this topic by myself?

Comment: You don't need a dome, just use a plane with a shadow catcher to make it look like it's on the ground

Comment: @Emir that was what I tried do to before discovering the dome method. I was not able to place the plane like it was the floor... The existing objects in HDRI didn't look well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would only use a dome for natural landscapes or things where you can match the scale of *your* objects to the background.

You aren't in control of the hdri, so you can't produce a version of it that matches your current needs.  Scaling your own objects could possibly produce some unwanted behavior.  Scaling the hdri generally is not possible - on one axis it is possible but introduces inconsistencies and camera movement becomes nigh impossible.

The hdri may also be too low resolution to be up to your standards when viewed as a background or a floor- even a very high resolution hdri may have visible pixelation since you're only viewing a small portion of it through the camera.

Some depth of field could work to blur slightly blur the parts of the scene you have a problem with, or even let you get away with lower fidelity assets if you decide you need to furnish a room with blender objects.

Comment: Bottom line: use HDRI just for distance/surrounding environments, but for real objects use real models.